# Unit Testing POST request body while using WebClient

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, webclient, spring-webflux

Below is a snippet of my code which POST multipart request to server.
Based on some condition, it decides to post only one file or both.

```
// Based on some condition add 1 or 2 files to the multipart body
MultiValueMap<String, Object> parts = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
if (postBothFiles) {
    parts.add("File_ONE", new FileSystemResource(file1));
}
parts.add("File_TWO", new FileSystemResource(file2));


// Perform the post request adding `parts` to the body
webClient.post().uri("/postUrl")
                .contentType(MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
                .body(BodyInserters.fromMultipartData(parts))
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class)
                .block();
```

During Unit Test, I want to test if the condition works correctly. To do that, by some means, I want to verify if the request body has two files or only one.

I tried using `ExchangeFilterFunction`, however it doesn't let me read the body content.

What is the best way to Unit Test such POST requests?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have 2 options.

1. make spy of `BodyInserters.fromMultipartData` using `PowerMock`. `PowerMock` can make `spy`/`mock` for static method.
2. consider to use  okhttp/mockwebserver(https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/mockwebserver#recordedrequest). It can record request body like below example.

```
MockWebServer server = new MockWebServer();
RecordedRequest request = server.takeRequest();
assertEquals("{}", request.getBody().readUtf8());
```